# Clang: Meaning of PLT32 in Godbolt

Tags: c++, c, assembly, elf, godbolt

Consider the following program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((noinline)) 
int add(int a, int b)
{
        return a + b;
}

int add_external_def(int a, int b);

int main() 
{
        printf("5 + 5 = %d\n", add(5, 5));
        printf("5 + 5 = %d\n", add_external_def(5, 5));
        return 0;
}
```

Compiling this program with Clang 17.0.1, for x86-64 with `-O3` will produce some assembly that is basically what I would expect. In this assembly, we call `add`, `add_external_def` and `printf` as follows ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/7f55sTqeo)):

```s
call add
```

```s
call printf@PLT
```

```s
call add_external_def@PLT
```

My understanding here is that `printf` requires resolution by the dynamic linker/loader and `add_external_def@PLT` will probably just be replaced during link time optimization (please correct me if I am wrong).

However, if I check 'Compile to binary object' these calls are replaced respectively with the following

```s
 call   20 <main+0x10>
    R_X86_64_PLT32 add-0x4
```

```s
 call   33 <main+0x23>
    R_X86_64_PLT32 printf-0x4
```

```s
 call   42 <main+0x32>
    R_X86_64_PLT32 add_external_def-0x4
```

What is the significance of this `R_X86_64_PLT32 ...-0x4` part? Where has the information about 'whether this function is to be resolved through the PLT' gone?

Comment: C or C++? As always, it matters. Both languages have "name mangling" of sorts, but C++ more so than C.

Comment: @Lundin I tagged C++ as this is essentially the same in both languages, as far as I can tell. The above program is both valid C and valid C++ and the question is more about the generated object file, rather than something specific to either language. Note that (effectively) identical assembly is generated in both cases.The hope is that knowledge of the answer to this question intersects quite well with people who have knowledge of C and/or C++.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commitdiff;h=bd7ab16b4537788ad53521c45469a1bdae84ad4a;hp=80c96350467f23a54546580b3e2b67a65ec65b66)

> On i386, there are 2 types of PLTs, PIC and non-PIC.  PIE and shared
> objects must use PIC PLT.  To use PIC PLT, you need to load
> *GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE* into EBX first.  There is no need for that on x86-64 since x86-64 uses PC-relative PLT.
>
> On x86-64, for 32-bit PC-relative branches, we can generate PLT32
> relocation, instead of PC32 relocation, which can also be used as a
> marker for 32-bit PC-relative branches.  Linker can always reduce
> PLT32 relocation to PC32 if function is defined locally.   Local
> functions should use PC32 relocation.  As far as Linux kernel is
> concerned, R_X86_64_PLT32 can be treated the same as R_X86_64_PC32
> since Linux kernel doesn't use PLT.
>
> is needed.  It is available on hjl/plt32/master branch at

Comment: Questions about the meaning of `@plt` (and what the PLT is) have been answered several times on this website. I am asking about the significance of `R_X86_64_PLT32 ...-0x4` in the case where I compile to a binary object. Key question phrase: **Where has the information about 'whether this function is to be resolved through the PLT' gone?**.